# using strncmp c-style string function

Tags: c, c-strings, strncmp

I have a string and I'm trying to find out if it's a substring in another word.

For instance(pseudocode)

```
say I have string "pp"

and I want to compare it (using strncmp) to 

happy
apples
pizza

and if it finds a match it'll replace the "pp" with "xx"
changing the words to

haxxles
axxles
pizza
```

is this possible using strncmp?

Comment: To elaborate: you can use a loop over the input string and `strncmp` at each position to see if you have a match. It's a little more code than the `strstr` solution, but it will work.

Answer (score 4):

Not directly with `strncmp`, but you can do it with `strstr`:

```
char s1[] = "happy";

char *pos = strstr(s1, "pp");
if(pos != NULL)
    memcpy(pos, "xx", 2);
```

This only works if the search and replace strings are the same length. If they aren't, you'll have to use `memmove` and potentially allocate a larger string to store the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! After all that cstring learning I did last semester it seems like I still have a lot more to go. I've never used strstr, nor have I used memcpy. Thanks again.

Comment: It's entirely possible to use `strncmp` to achieve this - it's easier with strstr, but that's another matter.

Comment: Worth noting: even though these are strings, we don't use `strcpy` because that's meant for copying whole strings (including their null terminators).

Answer (score 1):

Not with strncmp. You need [strstr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr) i.e.

```
char happy = "happy";
char *s = strstr(happy, "pp");
if (s) memcpy(s, "xx", 2);
```